# Can't download PDF from Umbraco media folder when using Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, umbraco8

I've got an umbraco 8.14.1 site configured to use Azure blob storage for the media folder. Images work fine, but when I try to link to a PDF I get a 404 with the body

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

If I replace the domain name of the site with the domain for the storage account I can view the PDF without issue, therefore the PDF is definitely in Blob storage.

Why aren't PDFs working but images are?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Umbraco to latest 8.17.1 I noticed there was a line added to ~/Media/web.config

```
<add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Adding that in live fixed the issue without upgrading.